# How do I fix "An Invalid dn syntax has been specified" in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Trying to get a simple script to work that is supposed to add a new user to an Active Directory domain. I keep getting the error :

"Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" argument(s): "An invalid dn syntax has been specified."

I've been researching this for over 3 hours on the Internet with no luck.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

The meager code follows:

```
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=NewHires,OU=Goropa Organization,DC=goropa,DC=com")

$objUser=$objDomain.Create("user","dubu")
$obJUser.Put("givenName","Butt")
$objUser.Put("sn","Butt")
$objUser.Put("sAMAccountName","dubu")
$objUser.Put("displayName","Dumb Butt")
$objUser.Put("userPrincipalName","duas@goropa.com")
$objUser.SetInfo()

#$objUser.AccountDisabled = $FALSE
#$objUser.SetPassword("Bob123!@#")
#$objUser.SetInfo()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$objUser=$objDomain.Create("user","dubu")
```

You have to use relative name of the object. Check out the documentation here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705987(v=vs.85).aspx

To fix it just replace the second line with:

```
$objUser=$objDomain.Create("user","cn=dubu")
```